# Angularjs on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm

Is it possible to use angularjs services like $q and $http on server side nodejs code? I have to frequently share code between server and client making it necessary to use libraries that work both on server and client.

Comment: Node has plenty of promise libraries and http libraries. Your business logic in your services should not be tightly coupled with any of these libraries or implementations. I see architecture issues here, more than the need to have $q and $http on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angularjs is a client side framework. I think the more appropriate question would be using Javascript on the server which are mpm mentions there is node.js for that.

The $q on the server side would be like using [the q library in node.js](https://npmjs.org/package/q).

The $http on the server side would be like using [the request library in node.js](https://github.com/mikeal/request)